# IntelliJ: how to set the color used for inspections in the IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know how to set the colour that Intellij  uses to display (Java) inspections. Almost every other colour in Intellij a can be customized and set - but not this one. I would would imagine it's because I don't know the name Intellij  uses to describe this class of object in its editor.

Comment: By *inspections*, do you mean warnings and errors in the editor?

Answer (score 4):

Code inspections color and any other color can be changed in the dialog on the screenshot. Simply look for it in the example text area if you don't know what is the name of the thing you want to change.

Inspections are under Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Error and Warnings

(IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3)

[image: IntellJ configuration window]